# How to fix this generic problem within the repository pattern?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I have a type converter which converts a string into an object and vice versa, the type converter takes the local into account. To implement easily several type converters, e.g. for `BigDecimal`, `Point`, and so on I decided to make this interface generic.

```
public interface TypeConverter<T extends Object>
{ 
    convertToString(Locale locale, T object);
}
```

This is great to implement as you can be sure you only get the desired T and don't have to cast or something else.

```
convertToString(Locale locale, BigDecimal bigDecimal) { ... }
```

To retrieve the correct converter, I build up a type converter repository where you can access a specific type converter

```
 typeConverterRepository.getTypeConverter(sourceValue.getType())
```

The type converter repository than gives us the correct type converter.

Now we want to call this converter:

```
TypeConverter typeConverter = typeConverterRepository.get( ....)
typeConverter.convertToString(context.getLocale(), sourceValue.getValue());
```

This leads into an eclipse warning:

> The method `convertToString(Locale, capture#2-of ?)` in the type `TypeConverter<capture#2-of ?>` is not applicable for the arguments `(Locale, Object)`

How can this be fixed without using the `@SupressWarning` annotation? Thank you!

Comment: Is your use of a non-generic `TypeConverter` intentional?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I think you mean the non-generic TypeConverterRepository? Yes, because I don't know the type in every case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem lies within your typeConverterRepository pattern.

Do a typeconverter that looks like the following

```
public class TypeConverterRepository {
    public <T> void registerTypeConverter(Class <T> type, TypeConverter<T> typeConverter);
    public <T> TypeConverter<T> getTypeConverter(Class <T> type);
}
```

Then you can safley do a

```
TypeConverter<MyClass> typeConverter = typeConverterRepository.getTypeConverter(MyClass.class);
```

Comment: This would be possible if I know in every case the class of the value, unfortunately this isn't the case: Often we get values from a model or view, where we don't know the type of the value, imagine a very generic function which just loads the value from a resource and tries to convert it. I don't know statically the class.

Comment: Why is this a problem? You can get the runtime class by calling getClass. Like the following:
    `TypeConverterRepository.registerTypeConverter(String.class,  stringTypeConverter);
    Object myString = "myString";
    TypeConverter<?> typeConverter = TypeConverterRepository.getTypeConverter(myString.getClass());`

Comment: I tried to use the `typeConverter`, it still is not applicable for any object if the type is `?`. The error remains the same.

Comment: There was an error in my post, Forgot to add the <T> to public <T> TypeConverter